# Variable symbol in Params object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-data, parameters

I have the following code:

```
@profile.update_attributes(params[:xxxx_profile])
```

where xxxx stands for either male or female.  Basically the form submit passes either a set of `female_profile[foo]` or a `male_profile[foo]` and i want to change it accordingly.  Assuming I have a string that can be inserted in lieu of xxxx, how do I dynamically create this symbol?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@profile.update_attributes(params["#{gender}_profile".to_sym])
```

or, you should be able to pass in the string without converting to a symbol, because Rails uses a HashWithIndifferentAcceess for params:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

```
@profile.update_attributes(params["#{gender}_profile"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  Thought it might be useful for someone.

```
@profile.update_attributes(params[(@sexstring + "_profile").to_sym])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
@profile.update_attributes(params[:"#{gender}_profile"])
```